# Shelf under sloped rear window of a car

Tags: phrase-requests

What is a good word or phrase for the shelf under the sloped rear window, behind the back seats of a sedan-style vehicle?

Comment: That was always the "back ledge" when I was a kid.  (Very bad place for parcels, by the way.)

Comment: In some American cars of a certain vintage, this is also the source of an astounding variety of squeaks and rattles.

Comment: Always called it the Back Dash  (US)

Comment: I've never had occasion to discuss that shelf, but if I ever did, I'd call it "the thing in the back window that's full of stuff I forgot I owned".

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's a [**parcel shelf**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/parcel-shelf):

> (automobiles) a shelf (which is usually removable) inside a car, located behind the back seats, and used to store small items. *There were a pair of toy dogs on the car's parcel shelf.* (-- Collins)

Edit - although the definition says 'removable', in my memory it was always used for fixed shelves prior to the widespread appearance of the hatchback (British English).

Comment: No denying the reference but it sounds very dated to my ears.  I think I say (to someone in the back seat as I drive) something like "... could you pass the map; it's on the shelf behind you".  If I describe this later I'd say "... it was on the shelf-at-the-back/back shelf".  Not as concise I know, but that's how it comes out!

Comment: Agreed - in fact, colloquially I've heard (and used) "it's in the back window" or even "it's on the back window" to describe the location. *"That car's got nodding dogs in the back window."*

Comment: Agreed!  I might even say it's in (*sic*) the back window

Comment: In Canada the term "package shelf" is used, parcel being a more British term for the same thing. Definition from the largest Canadian online auto sales site: http://www.autotrader.com/help/glossary/P.xhtml

Comment: "Parcel shelf" was in common use in the UK when I was growing up. It's certainly not made up. You will also find references in the wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcel_shelf

Comment: The handbook for my current European-designed car uses "rear parcel shelf" - presumably because some (bigger) cars have a "front parcel shelf" in the space under the dashboard, on the passenger's side.

Comment: In the UK, I was always told it's the parcel shelf, and nobody has been confused when I refer to it as such.

Comment: I've always heard "package shelf" in the US.

Comment: Words for car parts seem to have lots of regional variation. On TV I usually hear "glove box", but when I was growing up in New York we called it "glove compartment". And there's the well-known "trunk" vs. "boot" difference between American and British English.

Answer (score 22):

It is called [**rear deck**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rear--deck), **deck,** or more colloquially, **rear/back dash** in the US.

> deck: the horizontal surface at the rear of the car, which usually
> serves as the trunk lid.

[**Glossary of Automotive Design**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_automotive_design)

> *The flat area extending from the top of the backseat to the rear window is called "the deck" or "the rear deck" in **American English**.*
>
> *The commercial sites I looked at for alternatives confirm that
> Myridon's "rear deck" is used as well as "**rear dash**". Here's a link to
> a picture of covers that are being sold to cover the "rear deck/dash".
> I think "rear deck" is the preferred term for those who actually work
> with cars. Some of the sites use "rear dash" in their titles so that
> people can find them with a search engine.*

[**Word Reference**](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/rear-deck-or-rear-dash.2108299/)

> *Once he was sure the boy would stay, he placed the crumpled papers and the school cap on the rear deck and closed the door.* ([**The Taximan's God**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Gt7LGE-MePEC&pg=PT84&dq=%22cap+on+the+rear+deck%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAWoVChMI2sPV1qzHyAIVhgoaCh3dtQEj#v=onepage&q=%22cap%20on%20the%20rear%20deck%22&f=false))
>
> *Because the man was wearing a suit coat and unfashionable glasses,
> Rollins at first had guessed banking. Then he spotted an umbrella on
> the rear dash, and he reconsidered. Insurance?* ([**The Dark House**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=dGgWFv462HkC&pg=PA1&dq=%22because+the+man+was+wearing+a+suit+coat%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAGoVChMInY3dmK7HyAIVglQaCh2B1QtK#v=onepage&q=%22because%20the%20man%20was%20wearing%20a%20suit%20coat%22&f=false))
>
> *She spotted her Indians baseball cap on the back dash.* ([**Please Reply**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=EfokLWp1L48C&pg=PT136&dq=%22cap+on+the+back+dash%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAGoVChMIjYrPq6_HyAIVgVEaCh1KngZe#v=onepage&q=%22cap%20on%20the%20back%20dash%22&f=false))

Comment: I don't think the terms you're providing here all refer to the same thing. I think "rear dash" answers the question well, as it unambiguously refers to the area under the rear window, just like how the dashboard is under the front window. However, "trunk lid" is unambiguously the lid of the trunk, which is outside the car. The definitions for "deck" or "deck lid" don't all agree - "flat area extending from the top of the backseat to the rear window" is definitely what's being asked for, but "the lid of the compartment at the rear of the body" is probably not. "Rear dash" seems best.

Comment: An a context example, when talking to a car audio shop, they will typically mention door speakers for speakers located in the front (as they are usually mounted in the door, near the footwell) and deck speakers for rear speakers, as they are usually mounted in this area. This of course doesn't apply to trucks or hatchbacks.

Answer (score 6):

I've always called it 'the rear shelf'.  This is supported by a [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22rear%20shelf%22).

**Example**

"Can you get me my sunglasses from the rear shelf?"

Answer (score 4):

The existing answers address the actual name of the shelf.  I know exactly what you're referring to, and I'm sure auto manufacturers have a name for it, but I've never heard it referred to by name since there is rarely any reason to talk about the shelf itself.  More often, one would refer to objects placed on the shelf or the act of placing them there.  In that case, I've always heard it referred to with the idiom **in the back window**.  (US, various regions.)

Answer (score 2):

I've always [US] thought of it by the term **package shelf**, but can't recall where... it seems to be an official term (if you do a google search you can see numerous auto part sales sites calling it a "package shelf" or "package tray") such as [here](http://dynacorndepot.com/trunk-divider-package-shelf-challenger), [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EPKWHHU), [here](http://www.jegs.com/p/Auto-Metal-Direct/Auto-Metal-Direct-Replacement-Firewall-and-Package-Tray-Panels/1538539/10002/-1). Both terms are also mentioned at [Autotrader.com's glossary](http://www.autotrader.com/help/glossary/P.xhtml).

**Package tray** seems to be the "official" term (and "package tray panel" for the metal body panel that it sits on top of) - a google image search for that turns up technical drawings from the manufacturers, pages with official part names, etc, e.g. [here](http://www.lexussouthatlantaparts.com/showAssembly.aspx?ukey_assembly=790147&ukey_make=1082&ukey_model=15670).

Of course, just because it's called that doesn't mean you should put packages (except maybe very light/small ones) on it.

Comment: My grandparents called it either a package shelf or, less frequently, a hat shelf.  Nowadays it would be a potentially lethal place to put an unsecured packaged, but in those days vehicles travelled at much lower speeds.

Answer (score 1):

It has a name. It's called the 'rear deck'.

The trunk lid is also often referred to as the 'decklid' or 'rear decklid'.

Comment: The answer, *rear deck* was also posted by [Elian](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/280482/44619)